# Alternatives to optimization algorithms to solve optimization problems with a huge number of variables.

Tags: algorithms, systems-of-equations, math-software

My problem is to find the minimum of a function $f({\bf x})$ given a set of constraints $c({\bf x})={\bf 0}$. I could get the equations using lagrange formulation: $$ \triangledown_{({\bf x,\lambda})}(f+ {\bf \lambda} c({\bf x})) = {\bf 0}$$
Depending on the parametrization of my function $f$, the equations can be non-algebraic (invloving angles and their trigonometric functions simultaneously) or algebraic (using unit quaternions at a compromise of increasing the number of equations and variables). Without going into much details of the physical problem, I am solving it by considering a number of finite elements (say $N$). The higher the value of $N$, the better the modeling of the problem, the larger the computational time since the number of equations and variables increase linearly with $N$.

This is a standard optimization problem which can be solved using Matlab, Maple, etc. in seconds for up to $N=100$ given an intial guess of the solution. But, I get only one solution and it could be a local minima, thus, the assumed initial value plays an important role. I don't want to use any intial guess. So, I tried using Bertini (which uses homotopy continuation) to obtain all the solutions for $N=3$, where my number of equations and variables are already 18. It takes a while (about an hour) and gives me all the solutions. But it fails for $N>3$. 
I have looked into interval analysis methods but again I have to specify intervals for my huge number of variables which I wouldn't know.

I am looking for any suggestions on other algorithms or softwares that can numerically handle a huge number of small degree multi-variate equations with a huge number of variables in a considerable amount of time if at all feasible. The degrees of my equations are 3 at most and I don't think there are any positive dimensional components in the solutions.

Comment: The title asks about a problem class that is very broad,  even more than the optimization problem described in the body of your Question.  Perhaps a narrower framing  in the title would help attract attention.  The most useful details in advising you will be those of the smoothness and evaluation cost for the objective function (and gradient if available).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Probably the title is less broad and clear now?

Comment: I suspect the underlying nature of your problem is central to choosing a good numerical method for optimization.  You mentioned a finite element approximation, but the actual relationship to the quantity to be minimized is not explained.  The fact that when the number of elements $N$ used is smaller, the computation is tractable suggests the possibility of using a [multigrid method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigrid_method), or at least solving a sequence of problems to identify whether the local minimums that concern you can be isolated.